# Some fields is required

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-attribute

Why I'm having this kind of error that "Type of user is a required field" even I didn't add one.

here is the error log:
`a:5:{i:0;s:96:"Source model "capulus_customer/attribute_source_typeofuser" not found for attribute "typeofuser"";i:1;s:2951:"#0`

Comment: Do you have any extension from caplus?

Comment: no sir, I don't put any extension from capulus I don't even know where to locate that error. can you help me please @RahulKumarDas

Comment: Okay! So, when & where you're facing this error? Does it affect to your front-end functionalities? Or, the error is in log files only?

Comment: I cant create a new customer in backend it send me to error page "There has been an error processing your request" and then when I tried in frontend "Type Of User" is a required value. I don't even add this module or what. I think its happen when they backup the existing site at the same hosting but different folder then they extend the backup file. But I already delete that backup, does it affect?

Comment: Go to Admin Panel -> System -> Config -> Advanced, and check if any module similar to these exists, if it exists, try to disable it, clear cache & then try creating the customer.

Comment: Nothing exist same to that, all magento module was there. Can you help me more please.

Answer (score 2):

Based on log there i think there is custom attribute for `customer`

just search on database with `capulus_customer/attribute_source_typeofuser`

If you found result then just delete this `attribute` if not needed otherwise put `source model`

Comment: I found it in the database and I delete it already but it showing the same error. Can you help me please

Comment: just delete cache and try@winresh24

Comment: I just deleted sir @keyur

Comment: Here what happen when i created a customer in frontend http://i.imgur.com/Vf58PhF.png